# How to connect to Vertica Db on Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, odbc, vertica

I'm trying to connect to Vertica db on Codeigniter framework.

I can connect to Vertica manually using following code.

```
$conn = odbc_connect('verticaDSN', 'dbadmin', 'password') or die(odbc_errormsg());
```

But I couldn't connect using Codeigniter. You can see my database configuration of CI below.

**/config/database.php:**

```
$db['vertica'] = array(
    'dsn' => 'DSN=VerticaDSN;Server=10.10.118.5;Port=5433;Database=db_prod;UserName=dbadmin;',
    'hostname' => '10.10.118.5',
    'port' => 5433,
    'username' => 'dbadmin',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'db_prod',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**/controllers/myControl.php:**

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }

    public function index() {
        var_dump($this->mymodel->get_last_fifty());
    }
```

**/models/Mymodel.php:**

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database('vertica');
    }

    public function get_last_fifty() {
        $query = $this->vertica->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Filename: models/Mymodel.php

Line Number: 11

Backtrace:
```

Thanks for your helps,
Br.

Comment: You should remove real credentials from code.

Comment: Hi Tpojka, it didn't work.

Comment: pass you credentials as parameters !

Comment: I belive you need to point to the full path of the object "schema.table"